# Bad images while exporting to windows Unity 5.5.4

Tags: image, export, unity-game-engine, publish

I have a very weird problem , there are some images that gone fuzzy when exporting to windows , they appear good when exporting to android or even at the editor , what is the cause of this problem ?
here are the 2 images .
[image]

Good image

[image]

Comment: It could be some sort of shader issue.

Comment: Those look like two different images. Are they PNG? Are they 8, 24 or 32 bit?

Comment: they are the same image ,it is a game so  the yellow blocks are randomly positioned . 
The background image is 24 bit PNG image .

Answer (score 0):

Try to look the import settings or reimport them It could be a unity bug

Comment: i reimported them more than 1 time but the same problem exists

Comment: It looks like the same pic is getting repated try looking at the import settings and screwing around there